# Pass geolocation values from javascript to php

Tags: javascript, php, geolocation

I am trying to post latitude and longitude values to a php file where I can store them in a variable and then save it into a database. But I am having trouble passing the values from js to the php file. Below I am posting snippets. The javascript is in the same html file. I have also included the jquery file in the head.

```js
function showPosition() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
      var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'a.php',
        data: {
          latitude: latitude,
          longitude: longitude
        },
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
        }
      });
    });
  } else {
    var latitude = "";
    var longitude = "";
  }
}
```

```html
<body onload="showPosition();"></body>
```

Now in the file "a.php" I am trying to store these values in variables.

```
$lat = $_POST['latitude'];
$long = $_POST['longitude'];
echo $lat;
echo $long;
```

But the values are not getting passed from the javascript to the php. Where am I going wrong? Please help.

Comment: Does `console.log(latitude)` log the latitude?

Comment: 1. Are you getting any error messages? - 2. Is jQuery included in your <head>? - 3. Is the JS code in your <head> or in your <body>?

Comment: What does var_dump($_POST) look like?

Comment: @MatthewPage var_dump($_POST) shows nothing

Comment: @user3783243 where to do that?

Comment: @Sv443 I am getting an error on POST 500. Internal Server Error. on Send jquery.min.js. Also on Ajax jquery.min.js... The jQuery is included in <head>. The JS code is also in the <head>

Comment: After `var latitude = position.coords.latitude;`. If you are getting a 500 though that information should be in the question, along with whatever your error log contains and the other data in your PHP file.

Comment: ok guys thanks for the help. I realised where I was making the mistake. I removed the script from <head> and pasted it in <body>. Then it started working fine.